# Haskell refer to list of list element

Tags: haskell

--This line count how many 0 are in the list

```
hasZero :: [Int] -> Bool
hasZero x = 0 < sum [1 | y <- x, y == 0]
```

--In this line I want to count how many empty list are in the list, but I got compiling erorr.

```
hasEmpty :: [[a]] -> Bool
hasEmpty x = 0 < [1 | y <- [x], y == []]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your second method - you are missing `sum` which does the count in the first one, and you are wrapping passed list into another one, it should be `y <- x` as in the first one:

```hs
hasEmpty :: [[a]] -> Bool
hasEmpty x = 0 < sum [1 | y <- x, null y]
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```hs
hasEmpty :: [[a]] -> Bool
hasEmpty = any null
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you summed the elements of the list your list comprehension generated. In the second, you haven't done this. You also don't need to put `x` in brackets.

```
hasEmpty :: Eq a => [[a]] -> Bool
hasEmpty x = 0 < sum [1 | y <- x, y == []]
```

This is a peculiar way to accomplish this goal. The more idiomatic way (aside from using the existing Prelude function `any`) would be to use pattern matching and recursion.

```
hasZero :: [Int] -> Bool
hasZero [] = True
hasZero (0:_) = True
hasZero (_:xs) = hasZero xs
```

Using `any`:

```
hasZero :: [Int] -> Bool
hasZero = any (== 0)
```